# How to disable default setting for File Type and to modify it in Linux?

Tags: linux

When I save a file such as `filename.amf`, but output file type looks like `XML document (application/xml)` instead of `AMF type/amf`.

How do I register the `amf` extension?

Comment: I think it should be moved to super user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I create and save my file type in the usr/local share folder and then it works.